# Openshift: how to show images as static resources from inner folder?

Tags: openshift

Is it possible in openshift web-app to show (load) images from the inner folder *data* as they are static resources. I mean something like this

```
<img src=".../data/images/screen.png" title="just for sample">
```

where `data` is inner folder in openshift server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developer center [[1]](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/filesystem.html) you have a data folder which allows you to do just that.